# Javafx Donut Chart in FXML

Tags: java, charts, javafx, fxml, pie-chart

I want to do a Doughnut/Donut chart on JavaFX and searching I came to this example: [Can PieChart from JavaFX be displayed as a doughnut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121580/can-piechart-from-javafx-be-displayed-as-a-doughnut)

I Works really nice, but since I'm using FXML to make my GUI, I can't use this example. First, I tried to add the DoughtnutChart.java class as a @FXML var in the controller class of the panel where I want to insert it, but launched errors.

Then, searched in Google to make the DoughnutChart a custom component, but all the examples are based on Panes. Also, If I try to import  my donu.jar to SceneBuilder, the window to select a component is empty.

So, my question is: How do I implement this Doughnut Chart on JavaFX when my GUI is made on FXML?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First on my mind was. Use  shape-circle and put both things into Stack pane.Put circle on top of pie chart.Woala.. - Donut

Comment: You should be able to use your own class in FXML fairly easily (SceneBuilder is a different matter). What errors did you get?

Comment: The error I got was that I couldn't use "DoughtnutChart" as a controller for a regular FXML PieChart.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post some code (and the exact error message)? You should just be able to use `<DoughnutChart>` directly in your FXML, as you would with `<PieChart>`. It's not a controller, it's a `Node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the cause of your error is without seeing the FXML and the error message.

I got this to work pretty easily: the one thing to be aware of is that the `FXMLLoader` instantiates classes by invoking the no-argument constructor. If it can't find one, it tries to use a builder class as a back-up plan. So the one modification you need to make to [@jewelsea's DoughnutChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121580/can-piechart-from-javafx-be-displayed-as-a-doughnut) implementation is to add a no-argument constructor. (You could also define a `DoughnutClassBuilder`, but that's a lot more work, and doesn't get you any extra benefit.) So I did this:

```
package doughnut ;

// imports as before...

public class DoughnutChart extends PieChart {
    private final Circle innerCircle;

    public DoughnutChart() {
        this(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    }

    // everything else as before...

}
```

Then the following FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import doughnut.DoughnutChart?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="doughnut.SampleController">
    <DoughnutChart fx:id="doughnutChart" />

</StackPane>
```

with the controller SampleController.java:

```
package doughnut;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;

public class SampleController {
    @FXML
    private PieChart doughnutChart ;

    public void initialize() {
        doughnutChart.getData().addAll(
            new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
            new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25),
            new PieChart.Data("Plums", 10),
            new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
            new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30));

    }
}
```

and the application class

```
package doughnut;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            StackPane root = (StackPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DoughnutChartDemo.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

work exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace **this** with **super** in James_D answer to make it work.

For me the constructor looked like:

```
public DoughnutChart()
{
    super(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    innerCircle = new Circle();

    // just styled in code for demo purposes,
    // use a style class instead to style via css.
    innerCircle.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
    innerCircle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    innerCircle.setStrokeWidth(3);
}
```