# JavaFX 2D Doughnut Pie Separate Slice Chart

Tags: java, charts, javafx

I'm trying to make a donut chart like the chart in the image below:

[image]

i found a example by jewelsea in this thread:
[Can PieChart from JavaFX be displayed as a doughnut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121580/can-piechart-from-javafx-be-displayed-as-a-doughnut)

but is a circle over the chart, so i dont know how to move a slice of the chart, anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: it seems that neither regular pie charts allow for slice extraction